# t-student distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've got this problem:
[image]

Here, if $Z,W$ are independent random variables, and $Z$ has normal standart distribution and $W$ has $\chi^2$ with $n$ degrees of freedom, $T=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\frac{W}{n}}}$.
I don't expect to find any problems in $b$ and $c$ parts, but in $a$, I don't know how to find the conditional density. How could I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_w=(T|W=w) $, observe that $Y_w= \frac {Z} { \sqrt {\frac w n}} $ where $w$ is some constant value.

So $Y_w \text {~Normal} (\frac w n, 0)$, in other words $T|W $ is normal.

Comment: Oh, that's true, I overlooked that. Thanks.